# Aurelia repeat.for throws an undefined error with custom-element

Tags: binding, aurelia

I want to pass an array of objects.

I am passing the array of stores from one custom element 'Store' to another custom element 'store-front' using the `repeat.for` syntax.

I had originally called the `store-front`,  `store` and changed it to `store-front` in case that helped - but it didn’t.

I can log the array in the 'store' custom element. I also logged its instance (and it was an array).

Below is the error:

```
aurelia-task-queue.js?26b6:44 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'undefined' of undefined
at setKeyed (aurelia-binding.js?1bbb:1923)
at AccessKeyed.assign (aurelia-binding.js?1bbb:1461)
at NameBinder.bind (aurelia-binding.js?1bbb:5174)
at View.bind (aurelia-templating.js?f83c:1396)
at Controller.bind (aurelia-templating.js?f83c:3394)
at View.bind (aurelia-templating.js?f83c:1406)
at Repeat.addView (repeat.js?1ef5:240)
at ArrayRepeatStrategy._standardProcessInstanceChanged (array-repeat-strategy.js?783a:107)
at ArrayRepeatStrategy.instanceChanged (array-repeat-strategy.js?783a:29)
at Repeat.itemsChanged (repeat.js?1ef5:136)
at BehaviorPropertyObserver.selfSubscriber (aurelia-templating.js?f83c:3645)
at BehaviorPropertyObserver.call (aurelia-templating.js?f83c:3512)
at BehaviorPropertyObserver.setValue (aurelia-templating.js?f83c:3492)
at Repeat.descriptor.set [as items] (aurelia-templating.js?f83c:3600)
at Object.setValue (aurelia-binding.js?1bbb:3539)
at Binding.updateTarget (aurelia-binding.js?1bbb:4778)
at Binding.call (aurelia-binding.js?1bbb:4793)
at SetterObserver.callSubscribers (aurelia-binding.js?1bbb:295)
at SetterObserver.call (aurelia-binding.js?1bbb:3612)
at TaskQueue.flushMicroTaskQueue (aurelia-task-queue.js?26b6:140)
at MutationObserver.eval (aurelia-task-queue.js?26b6:68)
```

I have read somewhere that when Aurelia attaches the array observer, it becomes an object. But I cannot find any documentation on how to deal with this issue.

I can pass the stores to a plain `div` in the stores html - but I prefer to be more modular/composable.

### Stores.js

```js
import { customElement, useView, inject, bindable } from 'aurelia-framework'
import { EventAggregator } from 'aurelia-event-aggregator'
import { DialogService } from 'aurelia-dialog'
import { HttpClient } from 'aurelia-http-client'
import { getStoresTask, toVm } from './model'
import { getStoreTask } from './store-front/model'
import { style } from './style.css'
import { map, clone } from 'ramda'

@customElement('stores')
@useView('./stores.html')
@inject(EventAggregator, HttpClient, DialogService)
export class Stores {
  @bindable tenants
  @bindable userId
  constructor( emitter, http, modal ) {
    this.disposables = new Set()
    this.data = {}
    this.state = {}
    this.emitter = emitter
    this.http = http
    this.errors=[]
    this.style=style
  }

  attached() {
    this.reset()
    this.getStores()
  }

  getStores() {
    const onError = error =>
      console.error(error);

    const onSuccess = data => {
      this.data.stores = data
      console.log(this.data.stores)
      this.emitter.publish('loading-channel', false)
    }

    this.emitter.publish('loading-channel', true)
    getStoresTask(this.http)(this.userId).fork(onError, onSuccess)
  }

  // openModal(id) {
  //   this.this.modal.open( {viewModel: Store, model: id })
  // }

  reset() {
  }


}
```

### Stores.html

```html
<template>
  <require from="material-design-lite/material.css"></require>
  <require from="./store-front/store-front"></require>

  <div class="store-collection">
    <div class=" mdl-grid">
      <store-front repeat.for="store of data.stores" store-front.bind="store"></store-front>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

### store-front.js

```js
import { customElement, useView, inject, bindable } from 'aurelia-framework'
import { DialogController } from 'aurelia-dialog'
import { HttpClient } from 'aurelia-http-client'
import { getStoreTask } from './model.js'
import { style } from './style.css'

@customElement('store-front')
@useView('./store-front.html')
@inject(HttpClient, DialogController)
export class StoreFront {
  @bindable storeFront
  constructor( http, dController ) {
    this.disposables = new Set()
    this.dController = dController
    this.store = ''
    this.id = null
    this.state = {}
    this.http = http
    this.style = style
  }

  attached() {
    this.reset()
    this.getStore()
  }

  getStore(id) {
    const onError = error => {
      console.error(error);
      this.errors.push({type:'store', msg: 'error with getting store'})
    }

    const onSuccess = store => {
      this.store = store
      this.errors['store'] = ''
      this.openModal(id)
      this.emitter.publish('loading-channel', false)
    }

    this.emitter.publish('loading-channel', true)
    getStoreTask(this.http)(id).fork(onError, onSuccess)
  }


   colorChange() {
    //  console.log(typeof this.storeColors);
      // TODO: grab  b/ style and create a fucntion that chnages the color based on another input
      changeStoreColors(this.storeColors)
   }

   reset() {
     console.log('store?',this.store)
   }

}
```

### store-front.html

```html
<template>
  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-shadow--2dp mdl-grid__item mdl-grid__item--three-div" css="${style.storeColor}" ref="storeColors[$index]"}>
    <span class="mdl-grid__item-primary-content">
        <svg style="width:24px;height:24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
          <path fill="#000000" d="M9,19V13H11L13,13H15V19H18V10.91L12,4.91L6,10.91V19H9M12,2.09L21.91,12H20V21H13V15H11V21H4V12H2.09L12,2.09Z" />
        </svg>
      <span>${store.name}</span>
      <span class="mdl-grid__item-text-body">
        <p>Expiration Date: ${store.expirationDate} <br>
          Notification Date: ${store.notificationDate}</p>
      </span>
    </span>
    <span class="mdl-grid__item-secondary-content">
      <a class="mdl-grid__item-secondary-action" href="#"><i class="material-icons">star</i></a>
      <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--compact mdl-button--theme-dark mdl-card__action mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect" click.delegate="showStore(store._id)">MORE DETAIL</button>
    </span>
  </li>
  </div>
<template >
```

Comment: Would you mind posting the code as text? It'll make replicating the issue a lot easier.

Comment: sure - i will edit the question with the code

Comment: From your stack trace, it's clearly a bug / error related to reference binding via `.ref`, can you remove all relevant ref binding and re-check the result ? Or at least try to avoid using `ref` with same value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

The stack traces back to `.ref` binding. Check all of your `ref` bindings first. There is another issue related to `ref` and inheritance here, you can have a look in case you run into the same issue https://github.com/aurelia/templating/issues/533

---

**Original:**

It looks like this line is the problem in your `store.html`

```html
<store-front repeat.for="store of data.stores" store-front.bind="data.stores"></store-front>
```

Notice the `store-front.bind=data.stores`, you are binding to the array instead of each store in your `data.stores`.

Comment: sorry that was a typo from copying it over. I was playing around with different combinations of words (`this.data.stores` vs `this.stores` etc). Ill change it in my question. Thnnks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the problem is caused by two things:

1. You are trying to access the `stores` property of `data` in your view, even though this property doesn't exist at the time of databinding.
2. You're using the `attached` callback to call `getStores`.

I'd start by creating an empty array for the `stores` property in the `data` object:

`this.data = { stores: [] }`

And I'd switch to using the `bind` callback instead of `attached`.

Finally, it might be necessary for you to add an `if.bind="data.stores.length > 0" to the`store-front` element:

```
 <store-front if.bind="data.stores.length > 0" 
              repeat.for="store of data.stores" 
              store-front.bind="store"></store-front>
```

In this instance, it would be important to put the `if.bind` before the `repeat.for` so that it takes precedence.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Hi Ashley - thank you for the reply, I switched to the bind method, added an empty stores array in the data property on Stores and copied/pasted your code into the Store.html - I still have the same error. I also tried adjusting the if statement to just looking for data.stores `if.bind="data.stores"`and removing the stores attribute from the data property  still no dice

Comment: Alright, then we're gonna need to move on to creating a gist.run runnable repro. I'm headed to bed, but if you can get a repro running on gist.run, I'll look at it in the morning.

Comment: im still looking for an upto date aurelia gist / plunker to use as a skeleton to replicate this issue....

Comment: Im pretty certain this is to do with when Aurelia attaches the SetterObserver that turns the array into an object.

Comment: Here's a gist you can work from: https://gist.github.com/AshleyGrant/a8f11e779253a1c6abb44dbec77a8b83

Comment: Hey Ashley - @bigopon found the cause - I had a ref in the child component that was throwing an undefined. Thank you for your time!!